# how to check if there is any html.ValidationMessageFor error or not in asp mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

How to check if validationMessageFor is empty?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProfileSetting", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "ProfileSetting" }))
    {
        <div class="container">

            <button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Edit</button><br />
            @Html.Label("Username : ")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "details1 form-control", @placeholder = "Example: Bond007", Type = "text", required = "true", disabled = "true" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger",  @id = "username" })
            <br />
            @Html.Label("Email : ")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "details2 form-control", Type = "email", required = "true", disabled = "true" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" ,id = "email" })
            <br />
            @Html.Label("Password : ")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "details3 form-control", @placeholder = "Example: Bond23!", Type = "password", required = "true", disabled = "true" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" ,id="password" })
            <br />
            @Html.Label("Date of Birth : ")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "details4 form-control" ,@placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY",Type = "text", required = "true", disabled = "true" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, "", new { @class = "text-danger", id = "dob" })
            <br />
            @Html.Label("Phone No : ")
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "details5 form-control", Type = "number", @placeholder = "Phone No", required = "true", disabled = "true" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger", id = "phoneno" })
            <br />
            <label id="Successfully_Changed"></label>
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
            <br />
        </div>
    }
```

In Script:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {

                @{
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=>u.Username).ToString()))
                    {
                        <text>
                        alert($('#ProfileSetting').validate().valid());
                    $.post(
                        "/Home/EditProfile",
                                {
                            Username: $('.details1').val(),
                            Password: $('.details3').val(),
                            DateOfBirth: $('.details4').val(),
                            PhoneNo: $('.details5').val(),
                        }
                    );
                    $('#Successfully_Changed').html("Successfully Changed.");
                    $('#Successfully_Changed').show();
                </text>
                        } }
            });
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: To make a ajax call to the controller if it doesn't have any error than to hide the save button and save the data in h field in the database and disabling the field.

Answer (score -1):

In one of the comments, to your question you said:

> To make a ajax call to the controller if it doesn't have any error than to hide the save button and save the data in h field in the database and disabling the field.

If that is your goal to check if the form is valid before you make an ajax call, then this is the way to do it:

```
var form = $( "#formId" );
form.validate();
if (form.valid()){
    // All is good so do your ajax operation.
}
```

The [valid()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) method:

> Checks whether the selected form is valid or whether all selected elements are valid.